# msbuild to copy to multiple locations defined in item metadata

Tags: msbuild, metadata

I have an item with metadata I want to copy to perform some actions on and the result to occur in multiple locations,
for example, I want to copy the file to multiple locations:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MyItem Include="myFile.txt">
   <Out>c:\blah;c:\test</Out>
  </MyItem>
</ItemGroup>
```

how would I setup a target to create c:\blah and c:\test if they dont exist, then copy myFile.txt to c:\blah\myFile.txt and c:\test\myFile.txt

I also want to get the list of full output paths (c:\blah\myFile.txt and c:\test\myFile.txt) if I want to clean them during a clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to change the structure of you ItemGroup, you need to handle that you have a nested ItemGroup (the MetaDataElement Out). Therefor you will need to batch the ItemGroup MyItem to the target and inside you can batch Out. I made a small example project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project DefaultTargets="CopyFiles" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
 <ItemGroup>
  <MyItem Include="myFile.txt">
   <Out>c:\blah;c:\test</Out>
  </MyItem>
  <MyItem Include="myFile2.txt">
   <Out>c:\blah2;c:\test2</Out>
  </MyItem>
 </ItemGroup>

 <Target Name="CopyFiles"
      Inputs="%(MyItem.Identity)"
      Outputs="%(MyItem.Identity)\ignore_this.msg">

  <PropertyGroup>
   <File>%(MyItem.Identity)</File>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
   <Folders Include="%(MyItem.Out)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Message Text="%(Folders.Identity)\$(File)" />    
 </Target>
</Project>
```

The Output will be:

```
Project "D:\TEMP\test.proj" on node 1 (default targets).
CopyFiles:
c:\blah\myFile.txt
c:\test\myFile.txt
CopyFiles:
c:\blah2\myFile2.txt
c:\test2\myFile2.txt
Done Building Project "D:\TEMP\test.proj" (default targets).
Build succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
```

Comment: How do you then stop the files being copied if they have not changed?

Comment: It's hard to do in this constellation, because how can you be sure that is not changed in all places? You could add a seconed metadata and use it for outputs: `<Reference>c:\blah</Reference>` -> `Outputs="%(MyItem.Reference)\%(MyItem.Identity)"`

Second option would be to check during the copy task, if the files differ. In that way you could be sure that everywhere is the newest version, not only in the reference location.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a concept called [MSBuild Batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx).
It allows you to divide item lists into different batches and pass each of those batches into a task separately.

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles">
    <ItemGroup Label="MyFolders">
    <Folder Include="c:\blah" />
    <Folder Include="C:\test" />
</ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="myFile.txt" DestinationFolder="%(Folder.Identity)\">
        <Output TaskParameter="CopiedFiles" ItemName="FilesCopy" />
    </Copy>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles">

    <!--The item(s)--> 
    <ItemGroup>
      <MyItem Include="myFile.txt"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!--The destinations--> 
    <ItemGroup>
      <MyDestination Include="c:\blah"/>
      <MyDestination Include="c:\test"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!--The copy--> 
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyItem)" DestinationFolder="%(MyDestination.FullPath)" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <FileWrites Include="%(MyDestination.FullPath)\*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!--The output -->
    <Message Text="FileWrites: @(FileWrites)" Importance="high"/>

</Target>
```